# Is there a system or framework for non-programmer form creation?

Tags: frameworks

Anyone know of a system or framework for a non-programmer form creation? Not a full implementation, but something that handles the designer aspect and something that handles the displaying for being filled in. All the logic we'll be doing. Maybe just a pair of widgets.

We've got a client-server application into which normal users enter and modify data in a thick client and we want to allow the customers to update and create forms with another thick client application, rather than calling us every time they need a letter changed. We want something to do the display bits while we implement the various hooks and functions the system uses.

We're a java shop, but we expect that we're open to writing these clients in another language if it'll be easier.

Comment: If you have a more descriptive title, as I edited it, you are more likely to get a more appropriate response. I won't battle you for the title of your own question, though.

Comment: Sorry, I just accidentally clobbered your edit

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Xopus with a schema for the XForm could work.

http://xopus.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for XForms libraries and tools. XForms is a new-ish standard format for defining forms and there are some libraries and tools available for it. Haven't tried any of these myself.

EDIT:
This looks interesting: http://www.orbeon.com/forms/builder

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're a Java shop so this might not be the best tool for you, but from you description you look like a classic case for Infopath:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/default.aspx